# Python2.7 sending mail, why msg['To'] stay empty?

Tags: python, email

I am sending multiple recipients mail with a python script, and it works, but in the "To" in the mail, the field is empty. On every mail provider I tried.

Here is my code :

```
def send_mail(self, server, send_from, subject, attach, foo=None, bar=None)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    body = u"""<html> My Body </html>"""

    #Attach file pdf
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html', 'utf-8'))
    filename = 'fname.pdf'
    attachment = open(attach, "rb")
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename = %s" % filename)
    msg.attach(part)

    text = msg.as_string()

    if foo != None and bar != None:
        recipients = ["a@b.fr", "b@b.fr"]
        msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
        server.sendmail(send_from, recipients, text)
    else:
        msg['To'] = "c@b.fr"
        server.sendmail(send_from, msg['To'], text)
    sleep(1)
```

msg['To'] should be the "To" in my mail but it stays empty. (Even in the "else" with only one recipient). I can't find any help about it on existing question, so I come to ask for your help about that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the second parameter is a LIST of recipients. You need to change your line

```
server.sendmail(send_from, msg['To'], text)
```

to

```
server.sendmail(send_from, [msg['To']], text)
```

Comment: For the first block of "if", var recipients is a list, so I send the list (and problem still occur about the "To" in the mail). For the second block I only have one recipient, I still need too give a list of one element? I've done quite a lot of script like that with only one recipient and I checked, I don't give a list.

Comment: Hey, sorry. My answer is wrong as I misunderstood your question. I will delete this answer since its misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out:

`text = msg.as_string()` should be done after the assignement to `msg['To']` So it will appear in my `if` and `else` block juste before the `server.sendmail(send_from, msg['To'], text)` since all information written in the mail, even 'To', and 'From' are in the third argument `text` .